# jQuery Script Not Running in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

The following code works fine in every other browser except IE7.  In fact, with this enabled on the page no scripts will work until I have commented it out.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var pathname = $(location).attr('href');
if(pathname.indexOf('sess') === -1){
    var path = pathname;    
        }else{
    var path = pathname.replace(/sess[^&]*&?/, "");
}

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/save_page.php",
       data: 'last_page='+path
     });
});
```

I have checked for errant commas and can't find any.  If I pass a literal value through the Ajax call and comment out the rest of the function everything begins to work as it should but I need the whole function to work.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Also, why oh why are you doing `$(location).attr("href")`? Let me elaborate on what that does, that takes the location object, constructs a jQuery element selection set around it, and then tries to access its property as an attribute (which, it doesn't have since it's not a Node or Element). Instead, you could do `location.href` which does the exact same thing only it's more reliable, faster, shorter and works better.

Comment: Also, why are you supporting IE7 at all ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 1.9.1 and because I want to get the full url with the page plus params

Comment: @adeneo because whether I like it or not quite a few of the users of my site still use it and because they work in a corporate environment and they can't upgrade etc because they don't have admin rights which means either I still support it or I lose users

Comment: You might want to try `location.host + location.pathname` instead of that scary regular expression you have. In fact, if all you want to do is report this page to a server, this whole code can be reduced to something like `if(location.pathname.indexOf("sess") !== -1) new Image().src = "lastname=" + location.host + location.pathname` and make it a get request.

Comment: I need it to remove any reference to a param called sess and it's value but keep any other params intact. The scary regular expression was written by another stackoverflow user to help me achieve this

Comment: let your enterprise users know about Enterprise Mode so they can press their IE admins to upgrade them to the year 2014, http://love2dev.com/#!article/Internet-Explorer-Enterprise-Mode-Resources. This allows them to still run their out of data LOB applications but work in a modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm beginning to realise that it isn't going to work on IE7 but I need the script to carry on working as it is without excluding IE7 users completely so I used..

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.")!=-1)
```

to determine if the browser is IE7 and if so exclude that bit of script.  Hopefully the user will be able to persuade their admin to upgrade them to a different browser when they realise that it isn't working as well as it could.

But, for the record, I agree that in an ideal world we shouldn't be supporting IE7 etc but in the real world a lot of people still use it and a lot can't do anything about it.  I work within the medical and dental industries and a lot of hospitals etc (about 50%) are still using XP with IE7 with no immediate plans for upgrading despite knowing that XP is no longer supported by Microsoft.

**Revision to solution**

Ok, I have revised my solution, I am using `php` sessions now for passing around the `sess` variable that was previously in the url so I no longer have to try and take it out of the url whilst leaving the rest of the params intact.

So now I am using

```
var path = window.location.href;
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax/save_page.php",
       data: 'last_page='+path
     });
```

Which works fine in all of the browsers I am testing it in including IE7

Comment: Hardly an answer. Your script is short and should be able to work on IE7. Have you tried looking into the suggestions posted by Benjamin Gruenbaum?

Comment: @Greggg yes I have, but I need a way to get the full url with params but only remove the reference to sess whilst keeping the other params intact.  Benjamin Gruenbaums solution is an all or nothing approach which just won't work

Comment: If you only get the path like Benjamin said, and keep the rest in place, doesn't that get you where you want to be?

Comment: no, because it doesn't include the other params needed for the php functions